# Consuming lambda SNS event as type Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2>

Tags: events, aws-lambda, promise, aws-cdk

I don't understand what is the use case to use `Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2>` type when processing an SNS event.

```
export async function main (event: SNSEvent) {
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log('This is the record', record);
      });
    return {
      statusCode: 200
    }
  }
```

```
export async function main (event: SNSEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> {
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log('This is the record', record);
      });
    return {
      statusCode: 200
    }
  }
```

What is the benefit of using `Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2>` ?

Does it mean that I could define the event structure and not have it accepted, basically an if-else statement, but transformed in Web Logic? Can you point to an example if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

First question - do you have an API Gateway in use with your SNS?

The code you mentioned:

`export async function main (event: SNSEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2>`

just promises an APIGatewayProxyResult when returning. So it expects at least a statusCode and a body:

```js
 return {
        statusCode:202,
        body:"JSON"
 };
```

I think, what you mean is: `export async function main (event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2>`

I assume that you're using an API Gateway that triggers a SNS Topic that triggers a lambda. With APIGatewayProxyEventV2 you just get the whole payload from the ApiGateway. You can create an interface that extends this APIGatewayProxyResultV2 to define or rather extend the event's structure. In my case, I added my own queryStringParameters.

```js
interface ExampleApiProxyEvent extends APIGatewayProxyEventV2 {
  queryStringParameters: {
    par1: string;
    par2: string;
    par3: string;
  };
}
```